# Windows 10 UEFI Installation

Tags: boot, windows-10, uefi, gpt, secure-boot

I am trying to do a clean install of Windows 10 on ASUS N550JX. I have a Samsung 850 Evo SSD. I have deleted all my partitions using GPARTED.

The problem is whenever I boot up my USB containing windows I get the following the error.

```
Windows could not retrieve the information about the disks on this computer
```

I want to install Windows using UEFI Secure Boot.

Comment: Try another OS like *Ubuntu*, if that detects your HD **create an NFTS** partition within *Ubuntu* and try the Windows installation again

Comment: Ubuntu detects the HD. Could you further elaborate on the NFTS partition?

Comment: Sorry I meant **NFTS Partition within Gparted**. NFTS is a **format type that Windows can easily read and install onto**

Answer (score 0):

This means that Windows installation is unable to interpret the partition table of your disk. It can happen if you created a GPT partition table with gparted, or if any program created any partition table on the disk that Windows does not like.

Try to create a new MBR partition table in gparted. This will delete all your data from your disk, and restores it to the most common factory default state.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following tool:
[Rufus][1]

to create an Bootable USB Device

hit on the keyboard F12 when your system starts

try while you are in your windows 10 setup

1. Click install now.
2. Choose the second option of Custom Windows only.
3. You will be at the following step where it states where you want to
   install windows please make sure you delete all drives and you have
   one Drive 0 Unallocated Space
4. now you can just choose the Unallocated Space and click Next (if you are having problems click new and then select the appropriate drive you allocated.

This should solve the problem if you are not able to do the following steps

Please let me know if this helped you.

Comment: I already created a bootable USB drive using RUFUS. The problem is after I click INSTALL in Windows setup it shows the above mentioned error

Comment: i have updated the solution please read the added information :)